# Load pictures from local storage > OutofmemoryException - C# - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, out-of-memory

When i want to load pictures from internal storage, sometimes its to laggy but sometimes i get OutOfMemmoryException.

```
var picList = System.Instance.GetFiles("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera", true); //Its a string list, include the files name


                var inc = 0;

                foreach (var item in picList)
                {

                    var byteArray = FileSystem.Instance.ReadFile("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera", item.Split('/').Last(), true);

                    var toPicture = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(byteArray));

                    var image = new Image
                    {
                        ClassId = inc.ToString(),
                        Source = toPicture,
                        WidthRequest = 200,
                        HeightRequest = 200,
                    };
    `        }
    }
```

I think i need to dispose it but i dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you never invoke `image.Dispose()` method on image instance so memory allocated to image is never released. Also you should consider not loading all files but load them on demand.

Comment: I need to load all files unfortunately. Any idea?

Comment: If your users are using any of phones that I know it has about 2G of RAM (say half that is available to you considering operating system and other applications) and a camera capable of making 12Mpx images with 3 bytes per pixel that gives 36M per image so you can load around 25 images and do nothing else. Your requirement is unrealistic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare your variables outside the loop and reuse them, instead of declaring new ones at each iteration :

```
byte[] byteArray = null;
MemoryStream toPicture = null;
Image image = null;  

foreach (var item in picList)
{
    byteArray = FileSystem.Instance.ReadFile("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera", item.Split('/').Last(), true);

    toPicture = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(byteArray));

    image = new Image
    {
        ClassId = inc.ToString(),
        Source = toPicture,
        WidthRequest = 200,
        HeightRequest = 200,
    };
}
```

Comment: Not working. :( In this case there is only one picture. The last one.

Comment: This code doesn't do anything with the image created, it is just an optimization of the loop you wrote. Does the OutOfMemoryException still occur ?

Comment: No more OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: If there are so many pictures and they are big sized, the UI is so slow and laggy and the UI cant load all of them.

Comment: I have no idea how your UI works, please explain a little how you handle your images once they are loaded.

Comment: There is a listview. Itemsource is an ObservableCollection that include the pictures.

Comment: You shoud consider using virtualization to load images as you scroll them : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19930/listview-virtualization-for-loading-on-scroll